# snap.svg mina easing parameter not working

Tags: snap.svg

In the snap svg docs all mina.* easings have a parameter n available [(ie bounce)](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#mina.bounce), however when passing anything but a zero it errors, while passing a zero basically removes the easing effect. I was hoping that this parameter affected the intensity of the easing if passing a zero removes it, but maybe zero just works as its falsey? Am I missing something?

Below is an example:

```js
/* Timeouts are set just to show all three running */

var s = Snap("#svg");


var rect = s.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);

//Works without parameter

rect.animate({
    x: 50,
    y: 50
}, 800, mina.bounce)


setTimeout(function(){
  
//  
//Works with parameter as 0
//
rect.animate({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}, 800, mina.bounce(0));
  
  
},1000)


setTimeout(function(){
  
//
// Doesnt Work 
//
rect.animate({
    x: 50,
    y: 50
}, 800, mina.bounce(1));
  
  
},2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work quite as you think.

When you call an animation, you pass an easing function as an argument. That function will take a parameter 'when its called' (ie not when its passed) which will be the interpolated number between 0-1 where the animation is along its duration. So at the start of the animation it will be 0, then something like 0.01, then at the end 1. The function dictates how the result will vary, and will return a value of the current bounce depending on what the current input value (how far through the animation it is 0-1).

In your example, you aren't passing a function mina.bounce any more, you are passing the result of a function mina.bounce(0) (which is a number, not a function), so nothing will ever happen.

If you wanted a different easing effect (other than the included ones), you would need to write your own func and pass that as an argument to the animation (you could add a 2nd argument which dictates certain characteristics like strength of bounce, and then pass that as a bind to the function). You could have a look at the mina.bounce function and tailor it to your needs (you may to copy it and just change a couple of the values you see in the bounce func, but they are a bit fiddly).

You can see the example easing funcs [here](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/mina.js) near the end of the file.